# Metric-Fu/Rcov "No File To Analyze"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rcov, metric-fu

I'm trying to get metric-fu running on a rails project I'm working with. Every time it runs the rcov portion of the metrics I get:

```
** Invoke metrics:all (first_time)
** Execute metrics:all

No file to analyze was found. All the files loaded by rcov matched one of the
following expressions, and were thus ignored:
[/\A\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Ruby\.framework\/Versions\/1\.8\/usr\/lib/,
 /\btc_[^.]*.rb/,
 /_test\.rb\z/,
 /\btest\//,
 /\bvendor\//,
 /\A\/Library\/Ruby\/Gems\/1\.8\/gems\/rcov\-0\.9\.7\.1\/lib\/rcov\/formatters\/base_formatter\.rb\z/,
 /\bvendor\//,
 /\bconfig\//,
 /\benvironment\//,
 /\/gems\//,
 /\/Library\//,
 /spec/]

You can solve this by doing one or more of the following:
* rename the files not to be ignored so they don't match the above regexps
* use --include-file to give a list of patterns for files not to be ignored
* use --exclude-only to give the new list of regexps to match against
* structure your code as follows:
      test/test_*.rb  for the test cases
      lib/**/*.rb     for the target source code whose coverage you want
  making sure that the test/test_*.rb files are loading from lib/, e.g. by 
  using the -Ilib command-line argument, adding  
    $:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "lib")
  to test/test_*.rb, or running rcov via a Rakefile (read the RDoc
  documentation or README.rake in the source distribution).
rake aborted!
NaN
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/float/rounding.rb:19:in `round_without_precision'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/float/rounding.rb:19:in `round'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/metric_fu-1.2.0/lib/base/generator.rb:135:in `round_to_tenths'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/metric_fu-1.2.0/lib/generators/rcov.rb:84:in `to_h'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/metric_fu-1.2.0/lib/base/generator.rb:131:in `generate_report'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/metric_fu-1.2.0/lib/base/generator.rb:53:in `generate_report'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/metric_fu-1.2.0/lib/base/report.rb:54:in `add'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/metric_fu-1.2.0/lib/../tasks/metric_fu.rake:6
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/metric_fu-1.2.0/lib/../tasks/metric_fu.rake:6:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/metric_fu-1.2.0/lib/../tasks/metric_fu.rake:6
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Running rcov by itself comes up with the same problem. I'm using Rspec and not TestUnit if that helps.

Comment: What does your rake task for running rcov look like?

Comment: When I'm doing it with metric-fu i'm using the config found at http://metric-fu.rubyforge.org/

The rcov.opts when I run rake spec:rcov has the following options:
--exclude "spec/*,gems/*
--rails

All default stuff on both ends, but same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using rake to launch metric_fu you can add any directory to rcov path with this snippet:

```
begin  
  require 'metric_fu'
  MetricFu::Configuration.run do |config|  
     config.rcov[:rcov_opts] << "-Ispec"  
  end 
rescue LoadError  
end
```

This will add the **-Ispec** flag to rcov options, which in turn will add the 'spec' directory to rcov's path.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the "test" directory and added "--include spec/spec_helper.rb" to the Rcov configuration hash. I think it needs to be specifically pointed to the spec helper and you need to remove the test directory otherwise it tries to run rcov on testunit and not rspec.

Hope this helps other people!

Answer (score 0):

So rcov does this thing where it displays the "No file to analyze was found." message when problem is really the stack trace below the message.  You could try upgrading your version of rcov (what version are you on?).

Comment: My gem list reveals:

rcov (0.9.7.1)